Unable to boot to Windows, says boot disk is unavailable after installing Ubuntu
I have two drives, both 500 GB NVMe. One is the Windows drive, which I partitioned to install Ubuntu. I followed this video to do so. I am giving what information I feel is important, please ask me to add more information.
Linux boots OK, but my computer is unable to boot Windows. There is no specific error code at a blue screen, just a simple message that Windows boot drive is not accessible. In the attached image is what I am able to see from Windows.

I have also run the Boot-Repair tool on Ubuntu. Do I share it here (yes)?
EDIT: Adding the ubuntu boot-repair output.
    boot-repair-4ppa2081                                              [20241119_1702]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme1n1.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/cbmr_driver.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi 
                       /efi/OEM/Boot/bootmgfw.efi /efi/OEM/Boot/bootmgr.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p6: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p7: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

nvme1n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme1n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on nvme0n1p7
OS#2 (windows):   Windows 10 or 11 on nvme0n1p4

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] Alder Lake-P GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] from NVIDIA Corporation Intel Corporation
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic root=UUID=539492ba-b8c5-4d27-819b-dbf3c9a94c42 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
df -Th / : /dev/nvme0n1p7 ext4   81G   12G   66G  16% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: V1.11(1.11) from Insyde Corp.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager    HD(1,GPT,5e3bcfea-2416-4ecd-9ea8-f725ea96069f,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000034000100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,5e3bcfea-2416-4ecd-9ea8-f725ea96069f,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM    RC
Boot2003* EFI Network    RC


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1    : is-GPT,    no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,     not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
nvme1n1    : is-GPT,    no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,     not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os,    no-wind,    34 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p7    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-efi ,    grub2,    grub-install,    grubenv-ok,    update-grub,    end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    not-far
nvme0n1p6    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p4    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    end-after-100GB
nvme1n1p2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p5    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p7    : isnotESP,    fstab-has-bad-efi,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
nvme0n1p1    : is---ESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
nvme0n1p6    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    recovery-or-hidden,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme0n1p4    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    haswinload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme1n1p2    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme0n1p5    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot, 
nvme0n1p2    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot, 

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p7    : not--sepboot,    with-boot,    fstab-without-boot,    not-sep-usr,    with--usr,    fstab-without-usr,    std-grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme0n1p1    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme0n1p6    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme1n1p2    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme1n1
nvme0n1p5    : maybesepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme0n1p2    : maybesepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk identifier: 56FCA379-04AA-4F06-9926-9ABF7EFAE766
             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1      2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
nvme0n1p2    534528     536575      2048     1M Microsoft LDM metadata
nvme0n1p3    536576     567295     30720    15M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p4    567296  441231359 440664064 210.1G Microsoft LDM data
nvme0n1p5 614967296  998117375 383150080 182.7G Microsoft LDM data
nvme0n1p6 998117376 1000214527   2097152     1G Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p7 441231360  614967295 173735936  82.8G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk nvme1n1: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk identifier: 29BF0BCF-87D6-4180-9184-AFE8E23FDC65
         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme1n1p1    34     32767     32734    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme1n1p2 32768 976771071 976738304 465.7G Microsoft basic data

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1:512GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:Micron_3400_MTFDKBA512TFH:;
1:1049kB:274MB:273MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp, no_automount;
2:274MB:275MB:1049kB::LDM metadata partition:;
3:275MB:290MB:15.7MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres, no_automount;
4:290MB:226GB:226GB:ntfs:LDM data partition:;
7:226GB:315GB:89.0GB:ext4::;
5:315GB:511GB:196GB::LDM data partition:;
6:511GB:512GB:1074MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag, no_automount;
nvme1n1:500GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:MSI M371 500GB:;
1:17.4kB:16.8MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
2:16.8MB:500GB:500GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL      PARTLABEL
nvme0n1                                                                                                   
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     2E8F-8838                            5e3bcfea-2416-4ecd-9ea8-f725ea96069f ESP        EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               e1a423db-d95b-11ee-b025-d2baab529ff6            LDM metadata partition
├─nvme0n1p3                                               cc8f19c7-ef0c-4de6-8fcb-2eaef580669f            Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     F28C90258C8FE289                     7dd71d20-ae2f-4fa2-b3c5-c55995ecaed2 Acer       LDM data partition
├─nvme0n1p5                                               e108073f-a5ea-11ef-b051-4c034ff0262b            LDM data partition
├─nvme0n1p6 ntfs     D006907D0690666E                     c85d59f3-67e0-4c2d-8b8d-d068b6a69c00 Recovery   Basic data partition
└─nvme0n1p7 ext4     539492ba-b8c5-4d27-819b-dbf3c9a94c42 af195034-1e93-41ba-9cd5-a6632cc7efb7            
nvme1n1                                                                                                   
├─nvme1n1p1                                               9127c03f-fd45-4b40-b7ba-d1112579df3d            Microsoft reserved partition
└─nvme1n1p2 ntfs     84FCBEB5FCBEA0BA                     3979951e-3067-4b0e-af6f-95016bc51956 New Volume Basic data partition

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p4            42G  80% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p6           289M  72% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6
/dev/nvme0n1p7          65.2G  14% /
/dev/nvme1n1p2         143.1G  69% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme1n1p2
efivarfs                    0  99% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p4         fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p6         fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p7         ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/nvme1n1p2         fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 539492ba-b8c5-4d27-819b-dbf3c9a94c42 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p7/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   539492ba-b8c5-4d27-819b-dbf3c9a94c42
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme1n1p1)   osprober-efi-2E8F-8838
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p7/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p7 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/539492ba-b8c5-4d27-819b-dbf3c9a94c42 / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/2E8F-8838 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swap.img    none    swap    sw    0    0

==================== nvme0n1p7/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

================= nvme0n1p7: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 218.639785767 = 234.762682368  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 254.145503998 = 272.886657024  boot/vmlinuz                                   2
 254.145503998 = 272.886657024  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic                  2
 254.145503998 = 272.886657024  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 287.645503998 = 308.857008128  boot/initrd.img                                2
 287.645503998 = 308.857008128  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic               2
 287.645503998 = 308.857008128  boot/initrd.img.old                            2

=================== nvme0n1p7: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18133 Apr  4  2024 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43202 Apr  4  2024 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14513 Apr  4  2024 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Apr  4  2024 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13120 Apr  4  2024 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Apr  4  2024 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 Apr  5  2024 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr  4  2024 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr  4  2024 41_custom



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p7,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)


You are not showing the typically partitions an UEFI install of Windows normally has. Did you install in the old BIOS/MBR mode? Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode with gpt parttioned drives since 2012, so most systems now are UEFI. Laptop Systems since about 2020 are now UEFI only. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs for both Ubuntu & Windows. Both need to be in same boot mode & with newer systems, both should be UEFI/gpt.

As i Said, i just followed the linked you tube guide for installing. I remember choosing the "from drive" option then choosing an "EFI ****" option.

It looks like standard UEFI installs. But you have old BIOS boot loader in gpt's protective MBR which never should be used and will not work. If you directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu, does it not boot. If not then you need Windows repairs. Boot-Repair is only for Linux, primarily grub fixes.

I’m voting to close this question because because it is clearly a Windows problem and should be submitted on superuser.com

Windows does not boot from the UEFI menu. It just cycles back saying boot device inaccessible. I will try to look into how to do windows repairs. Most guides I've seen use a registry save in windows that I don't have or show that I need another disk in "disk vol" around 500MB in space. Which as the picture shows, is absent.

I have tried windows recovery, but it does not work. I want to completely remove windows and Ubuntu from my laptop and do a complete clean window reinstall. Any advice regarding this would be really helpful.
